# Connectedness and intersection problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and let $K_1,K_2,\dots$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$ which are nonempty, closed, and connected, and which satisfy $K_{n+1}\subset K_n$ for every positive integer $n$. Prove that intersection of $K_n$ for $n$ from $1$ to infinity is connected.

So, this was clearly marked as one of the hardest problems on review sheets, but if anyone could offer any hint or idea on where to start I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the intersection be $K$. If $K$ is disconnected, then there exist disjoint open sets $O,Q$ such that $O\cap K \neq \emptyset, Q\cap K \neq \emptyset$ and $K\subset O\cup Q$. Since each $K_n$ is connected, there exist $x_n\in K_n$ such that $x_n\notin O\cup Q$ (otherwise $K_n\subset O\cup Q$, impossible by connectedness). By compactness of $X$, $x_n, n=1,2,\cdots$ has a cluster point $x$. Since the complement of $O\cup Q$ is closed, $x\notin O\cup Q$. But $x\in \bigcap K_n=K$, a contradiction.